# Location service giving beep sound every second above android 8.0 version

Tags: android, location, tracking

I am running the background service in that iam using location service to get the current location. For every second it gives a beep sound in above android 8.0 version. How to avoid that sound while tracking the location.

Please help me to solve my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is something device- or your code-specific, it does not beep when using location.

Comment: in normal devices it is working fine. above 8.0 version it is giving notification sound for every minute.

Comment: it does not give any sounds on above 8.0 normally. It is something wrong with your device or with your code

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I turn off the notification sound for when apps request the current location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194626/how-do-i-turn-off-the-notification-sound-for-when-apps-request-the-current-locat). I haven't played around with Android 8.0 yet so haven't studied the details, but I'd suppose the notification/sound appears only when location updates are requested, so it will matter if you request location updates only once and keep them coming or if you cyclically request and cancel location updates all the time.